# select table boxes counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

have this fiddle and i would like to make it count the number of boxes that are selected. Now it shows the numbers of the boxes.

Any idea how to do it??

```
 $(function() {
    $(".selectable").selectable({
        filter: "td.cs",

        stop: function() {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            var result2 = $("#result2");
            $('.ui-selecting:gt(31)').removeClass("ui-selecting");

            alert($(".ui-selected").length);
            if ($(".ui-selected").length > 4) {
                $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(i, e) {
                    if (i > 3) {
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
                    }
                });
                return;
            }

            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                var cabbage = this.id + ', ';
                result.append(cabbage);
            });

            var newInputResult = $('#select-result').text();
            newInputResult = newInputResult.substring(0, newInputResult.length - 1);
            result2.val(newInputResult);
        }
    });
});​
```

my problem is to show the result of maximum selected boxes allowed. for example if you select 8 boxes to show only 4 and get result of 4 that is the maximum alowed. And finaly not to be an alert, to show in div tag or similar

http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/46/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show message like this [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/50/)

```
$('#divmsg').html($(".ui-selected").length + " box selected")
if ($(".ui-selected").length > 4) {
         $('#divmsg').html($('#divmsg').html() + ", Selection of only 4 allowed");
         $(".ui-selected").each(function(i, e) {                  
         if (i > 3) {
                        $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
         }
        });
        return;
  }
```

Comment: very nice!! also to show the number of boxes selected but not in alert way in a div tag!

Comment: very very nice you are helpful and the last question i have is how can i multiply the selected boxes with 2? example 40 boxes X 2=80

Comment: how can i do this multiplication?

Comment: can u show it as a different result? e.g. 1 box selected, 2 pixels